# Error: CallDepthOverflow when running Powershell startup scripts using Group Policy

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, startup, startupscript

I am trying to run a powershell script using Startup in a Group Policy. I have mapped the script in Powershell Scripts Tab under Startup section of the GPO. The script contains a one liner command to set the TimeZone information. Below is the code:

```
Set-TimeZone -Id "India Standard Time"
```

Below is the error msg:

```
Error Message = The script failed due to call depth overflow.
Fully Qualified Error ID = CallDepthOverflow


    Context:
    Severity = Warning
    Host Name = ConsoleHost
    Host Version = 5.1.17763.592
    Host ID = 836b5c03-9d27-402c-b8da-a169188ff709
    Host Application = -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File Set-TimeZone.ps1
    Engine Version = 5.1.17763.592
    Runspace ID = 23e7e0db-3eb1-404c-828d-aefbd89b8e01
    Pipeline ID = 1
    Command Name =
    Command Type =
    Script Name =
    Command Path =
    Sequence Number = 26
    User = LION\SYSTEM
    Connected User =
    Shell ID = Microsoft.PowerShell
```

The command works when I run the command manually.

Thanks,
Rajiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you encounter comes from the fact that you have named your script file with **the same name of the cmdlet you are trying to execute**.

Now the script is calling itself time and again..

Rename your script file into something like `Set-IndiaTimeZone.ps1` so it is not the name of a cmdlet you are using inside the script and it should work as expected.